# Freeze a function after running it one time

Tags: python, function

Say that i have a function who generates a list. The function costs significant amount of memory to evaluate, so I only want to use it once. After generating the output, I like to do calculations with the output without evaluate the function every time I'm running the code.

For example:

```
def heavy(x):
    bignumber = x + 3

    return bignumber


docalc = bignumber(10)
```

..Now when I do calculations with docalc and press run, I don't want the function heavy to run.
Can you freeze a function/tell it to only do one calculation without using # and """ afterwards?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a decorator that creates a cache of the function results:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def heavy(x):
    print("evaluating heavy for",x)
    return x + 3
```

output:

```
print(heavy(5))
print(heavy(5))
print(heavy(3))
print(heavy(5))

evaluating heavy for 5
8
8
evaluating heavy for 3
6
8
```

If this is between runs of the program (as opposed to runs of the function), you should save the value to a file and read it back when you start the program (only save to the file when the file is not there).